# jolt transformation - unnesting problem with json

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to make jolt transformation for this kind of json:

```
{
  "id" : "6aa0734f-6d6a-4b95-8a2b-2dde346f9df7",
  "ts" : 1583684304500000,
  "measurements" : {
    "A4" : {
      "value" : 164341584
    },
    "A5" : {
      "value" : -20486832
    }
}}
```

In the end I need to get something like this:

```
{"id" : "6aa0734f-6d6a-4b95-8a2b-2dde346f9df7",
"ts" : 1583684304500000,
"A4" : 164341584,
"A5" : -20486832
}
```

that kind of spec do I need to use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jolt spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ts": "ts",
      "id": "id",
      "measurements": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input:

```
{
  "id": "6aa0734f-6d6a-4b95-8a2b-2dde346f9df7",
  "ts": 1583684304500000,
  "measurements": {
    "A4": {
      "value": 164341584
    },
    "A5": {
      "value": -20486832
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "ts" : 1583684304500000,
  "id" : "6aa0734f-6d6a-4b95-8a2b-2dde346f9df7",
  "A4" : 164341584,
  "A5" : -20486832
}
```

Works with any number of A's. Try it here: https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! 
Can you please give me reference link to learn about syntax of JOLT using?

Comment: @KirillDemidov https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java